# Terminal de VSCode me muestra dos directorios unidos por "&" (ampersand)

Tags: python, vscode, powershell

Usando Visual Studio Code. Cuando ejecuto el código la PowerShell de Windows me muestra dos directorios unidos con un "&". Este es el output de la terminal. Creo que por esta razón tengo problemas para utilizar `sys.argsv` de Python.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

PS C:\Users\Familia\Desktop\Cursos Programación\Curso Digitalers\Modulo 3 - Python Programming\src> & C:/Users/Familia/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe
```

Tal vez el problema tiene que ver con que estoy trabajando con Python 3.8 en Windows 7 y por problemas en la instalación tuve que agregarlo al *Path* manualmente añadiendo la carpeta donde está instalado a la variable de entorno de sistema.

Edit con código:

```
def saludar(nombre):

    
    return(f"Hola {nombre.capitalize()}")

def leer_archivo(archivo):
    print(os.path.exists(archivo))
    f = open(archivo, "r")
    lineas = f.readlines()
    for l in lineas:
        print(l.strip())


def run_git():
    subprocess.run(["git", "status"])

args=sys.argv


print(args[0])

#print(args[1])


try:

    if "--saludar" in args[1:]:
        saludar(args[2])
    elif "--leer archivo" in args[1:]:
        leer_archivo(args[2])
    elif args[1]=="git":
        run_git()
    elif args[1]=="clima":
        de_que_lugar= args[2]
        subprocess.run([ "firefox", "--new-window", f"https://www.google.com/search?q=clima+{de_que_lugar}"])

  
except IndexError:
    print("Numero de parametros invalido")
```

Acá le paso a la terminal de VSCode los nombres --saludar pepe, para que responde según el codigo:

```
PS C:\Users\Familia\Desktop\Cursos Programación\Curso Digitalers\Modulo 3 - Python Programming\src> --saludar pepe
```

El output que obtengo después es:

```
Falta una expresión después del operador unario '--'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 3
+ -- <<<< saludar pepe
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (--:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Comment: Y tienes algún error con tu código?

Comment: Hola Christian! hice un edit en el post original. Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es como VS Code intenta ejecutar su código y depende de como este configurado y la opcion que usted seleccione de ejecución ¿A que me refiero?

Si su editor lo tiene configurado con PowerShell como terminal este para ejecutar una instrucción se le pasa `&` (ampersand) antes de la ruta del archivo a ejecutar y el archivo a ejecutar es `python.exe` y luego a ese archivo de tipo ejecutable le pasa como argumento su archivo a ejecutar `mi_archivo_a_ejecuta.py` algo así seria.

`& "carpeta/donde/esta/python38/python.exe" "ruta/de/mi_archivo_a_ejecuta.py"`

Esto en una ejecución IDEAL, pero lo más probable es que lo esta ejecutando para el interprete interactivo, es decir cuando le de ejecutar va a ejecutar Python sin argumento (sin archivo) y luego insertar la línea o líneas de código.

`& "carpeta/donde/esta/python38/python.exe"` y luego se abrirá en interprete interactivo e insertará su código como si lo hubiese ingresado manualmente por teclado.

**Que puede hacer usted, en la esquina superior derecha aparece un símbolo de PLAY se da click ahí y deberia funcionar bien**

Comment: Muchas gracias!